# Can't Access Database After Editing Views in Odoo 10: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo-view

I'm  working on Odoo 10.0 CE (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS).

After editing views from Technical (Login Layout - web.login_layout) **I set its Inherited View with Web layout - web.layout.** I couldnt login to the database & its showing like this (traceback attached below). How to fix this?

I tried to update the database & module through command line as User, but it didnt work, still can't login to the database

Is there any way that i can edit/undo the Views (Web layout - web.layout) through command line (database)?

Thanks :)

```
500: Internal Server Error
Error

Error message:

load could not load template
Template: web.layout

Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 274, in _handle_exception
    response = super(Http, cls)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 169, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 775, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 195, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 834, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 334, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 330, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1277, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1270, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/app_odoo_customize/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 18, in render_template
    return super(View, self).render_template(template, values=values, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1049, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 115, in render
    return super(View, self).render(values, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 26, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1069, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 53, in render
    return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 249, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 318, in _compiled_fn
    raise e
QWebException: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 342, in get_template
    document = options.get('load', self.load)(template, options)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 81, in load
    template = env['ir.ui.view'].read_template(name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 944, in read_template
    return self._read_template(self.get_view_id(xml_id))
  File "<decorator-gen-9>", line 2, in _read_template
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 87, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 935, in _read_template
    arch = self.browse(view_id).read_combined(['arch'])['arch']
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 674, in read_combined
    arch = self.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, root.id, self.model)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 623, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = self.apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree, view_id)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 601, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(_("Element '%s' cannot be located in parent view") % tag, inherit_id)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 474, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Element '<t name="Web layout" t-name="web.layout">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `Web layout`
[view_id: 165, xml_id: web.layout, model: n/a, parent_id: 166]

load could not load template
Template: web.layout
```

Comment: Any help? I tried to update web, website & base modules as odoo user from terminal, but still no result :(